# How to add more row at the mail designer in Mailchimp?

Tags: mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp mail template designer to create the template

First I select the basic template here:

[image: template selector - 3:1:3 column structure]

And when I edit the template

[image: editing the template]

I would like to create more rows at the template, e.g. 3 lines of photos instead of 2 lines now, anyone have experience adding more rows (and can select 1/2/3 column) at the mail template design?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are willing to code your own template, **basic templates have predefined sections that cannot be duplicated**.

That is why when you go to the Content tab you do *not* see any columns option.

[image: mailchimp-01.png]

What you can do though, is to add more elements by duplicating them or by using drag and drop. **But always within the predefined sections of the template**.

---

### How to add a new row of images

Judging from your screenshot you chose the "*3:1:3 Column - Banded*" template.
When you click on the design tab you can see the different sections of the template.

[image: mailchimp-02.png]

We try the "*Lower Columns Design*". (I have colored the section's background and borders so as to stand out).

[image: mailchimp-03.png]

When we take a closer look we see that the section has 3 separate columns.

[image: mailchimp-04.png]

We can add more image rows within this section by either duplicating the individual image placeholders,

[image: mailchimp-05.png]

*or* using drag and drop,

[image: mailchimp-06.png]

**for each column of the section**. This way we can have as many rows as we want.

[image: mailchimp-07.png]